# Reading data from xml file and storing as key value pair

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have following data in XML file where i have stored some testdata.

```
<root>
    <event>
        <auth>
            <admin>
                <username>testust@mail.com</username>
                <password>pass^&*%s</password>
                <name>temp</name>
            </admin>

            <normal-user>
                <username>test_usera1@mail.com</username>
                <password>test45#</password>
            </normal-user>

        </auth>
    </event>
</root>
```

I'm trying to read the data from xml in key value pair.
e.g.  `event.auth.admin.username = testust@mail.com` . Its working fine if i put all other data node under admin but if i user another node `<normal-user>` then it append this node name in older one.

Actual : `event.auth.admin.normal-user.username = test_usera1@mail.com`

Expected : `event.auth.normal-user.username = testust@mail.com`

I'm using below code for that:

```
private StringBuilder keyName = new StringBuilder();
Logger printLog = Logger.getLogger("API Testing Logger");

public void loadXml() {
    File folder = new File("resources");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {

            printLog.log(Level.INFO, "xml file loaded : " + file.getName());

            try {
                File inputFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file.getName());
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                new XmlLoader().fillDataInProperty(doc.getDocumentElement());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public void fillDataInProperty(Node node) {

    if (!node.getNodeName().equals("root")) {

        if (node.getChildNodes().getLength() == 1) {
            keyName.append(node.getNodeName());
            int i = keyName.indexOf(node.getNodeName());
            if (i != -1) {
                keyName.delete(i, i + keyName.length());
            }

        } else {
            keyName.append( node.getNodeName().concat("."));

        }
    }

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            fillDataInProperty(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to break the algorithm into these steps:

1. Collect all the leaf Elements, i.e. Elements without any child Elements
2. For each leaf Element, construct the key name by walking up the parent chain and the key value by getting the leafs text data:

Here's a complete example:

```
static String XML =
        "<root>\n" +
        "    <event>\n" +
        "        <auth>\n" +
        "            <admin>\n" +
        "                <username>testust@mail.com</username>\n" +
        "                <password>pass</password>\n" +
        "                <name>temp</name>\n" +
        "            </admin>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "            <normal-user>\n" +
        "                <username>test_usera1@mail.com</username>\n" +
        "                <password>test45#</password>\n" +
        "            </normal-user>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "        </auth>\n" +
        "    </event>\n" +
        "</root>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes()));
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    List<Element> leafs = new ArrayList<>();
    gatherLeafElements(root, leafs);
    for(Element e: leafs) {
        System.out.println(createProperty(root, e));
    }
}

static String createProperty(Element root, Element leaf) {
    List<String> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    Element tmp = leaf;
    while(tmp != root) {
        stack.add(0, tmp.getNodeName());
        tmp = (Element) tmp.getParentNode();
    }
    String property = stack
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("."));
    return property + "=" + leaf.getTextContent().trim();
}

static void gatherLeafElements(Element e, List<Element> leafs) {
    if (isLeafElement(e)) {
        leafs.add(e);
        return;
    }
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    while(child != null) {
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            gatherLeafElements((Element) child, leafs);
        }
        child = child.getNextSibling();
    }
}

static boolean isLeafElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    while(child != null) {
        if (child.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return false;
        }
        child = child.getNextSibling();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is when you have multiple child nodes, here is a solution with recursion which tries to address the issue:

```java
public void loadXml() {
  // ..
  new XmlLoader().fillDataInProperty(doc.getDocumentElement(), "");
}
```

```java
public void fillDataInProperty(Node node, String parent) {
    if (parent.isEmpty()) {
        parent = node.getNodeName();
    } else {
        parent = parent + "." + node.getNodeName();
    }

    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i=0; i< node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = childNodes.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            fillDataInProperty(currentNode, parent);
        } else if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE && childNodes.getLength() == 1) {
            keyName.append(parent + " = " + currentNode.getTextContent().trim(); + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and `System.out.println(p.keyName.toString());` now prints:

```
root.event.auth.admin.username = testust@mail.com
root.event.auth.admin.password = passs
root.event.auth.admin.name = temp
root.event.auth.normal-user.username = test_usera1@mail.com
root.event.auth.normal-user.password = test45#
```